# How to get "massless" equation of motion from the action of Nordstrom scalar field theory?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, variational-principle

There is [Nordstrom theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordstr%C3%B6m%27s_theory_of_gravitation) of the particle moving in a scalar field $\varphi (x)$:
$$
S = -m\int e^{\varphi (x)}\sqrt{\eta_{\alpha \beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d \lambda}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d \lambda}}d\lambda .
$$
How to get the equation of motion for massless objects? In this case I may introduce new parameter $\sqrt{\eta_{\alpha \beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d \lambda}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d \lambda}}d\lambda = \frac{d\tau }{m}$.

But when I try to derive (like [this way](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92021/how-to-derive-the-equations-of-motion-from-the-nordstrom-theory-of-scalar-gravit)) the equations of motion, I get
$$
\partial_{\alpha } \varphi = m^{2}\frac{d }{d \tau}\left( u_{\alpha} e^{\varphi}\right)e^{-\varphi}.
$$
Unfortunately, this equation doesn't predict the absense of deflection of light. But Nordstrom theory really predicts the deflection of light. So where is the mistake in my 
reasoning?

Addition.

I got the mistake. By introducing new parameter $\tau$ I must rewrite my equation in a form
$$
\partial_{\alpha } \varphi = \frac{1}{m^2}\frac{d }{d \tau}\left( p_{\alpha} e^{\varphi}\right)e^{-\varphi}.
$$
So it really preficts no deflection of light.

Comment: You should add your edit as an answer.